# Equinox Jetty: ClassNotFound when trying use JDBCSessionManager

Tags: jetty, osgi, embedded-jetty, equinox

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException from Jetty (Equninox embedded) when trying to use JDBCSessionManager and JDBCSessionIdManager.

Exception:

```
2017-01-06 10:37:02.620:WARN:oejss.JDBCSessionManager:qtp1215746443-29: Unable to load session 192168178229yf02ln7ut25phh97b49003w
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.HttpSessionAdaptor$ParentSessionListener cannot be found by org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.3.9.v20160517
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager$1.run(JDBCSessionManager.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager.loadSession(JDBCSessionManager.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager.getSession(JDBCSessionManager.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager.getSession(JDBCSessionManager.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.checkRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using a JettyCustomizer to hook into the Jetty startup to change the default HashSessionManager with the JDBCSessionManager. The JettyCustomizer is located in a Fragment Bundle which belongs to

```
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty
```

I got this idea from https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#How_can_I_use_Jetty_basic_authentication_in_my_application.3F

This setup works ok, and JDBCSessionManager places a session in the Database. The session is Serialized to a Byte-BLOB and stored in the DB. I can see it there.

But it seems the serialization is done by org.equinox.http and it places class reference like `org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.HttpSessionAdaptor$ParentSessionListener` into the BLOB.

Note, that `internal.servlet.HttpSessionAdaptor` is an internal class which is not exported to other bundles.

Now when the session information is read again from the database (e.g. when I access the webpage again later with the same sessionCookie) I run into this problem when `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.java:59)` tries to load the class`HttpSessionAdaptor$ParentSessionListener` but cannot see it (because it is a) internal and / or b) in another bundle.

`org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream` lives in bundle `org.eclipse.jetty.util` but `org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.HttpSessionAdaptor$ParentSessionListener` lives in bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet`.

**org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream** seems to do the following:

```
@Override
    public Class<?> resolveClass (java.io.ObjectStreamClass cl) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            return Class.forName(cl.getName(), false, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            return super.resolveClass(cl);
        }
    }
```

Is there anybody from the OSGI experts with an ideas?

I would describe the problem as that Session byte-BLOB contains Class References to **internal** classes which cannot be seen by `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassLoadingObjectInputStream.resolveClass`

Does that seem like a bug? Or is the approach with the FragmentBundle with the the wrong approach? (IMO it is the only way I found to exchange the SessionManager)

Comment: Could this be related? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498408 "HttpSessionAdapter attribute doesn't return string but object name string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably because `ClassLoadingObjectInputStream` is using the TCCL for class resolution, which - in Equinox - by default is the `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder`. It is finding the first bundle on the call stack. This is likely the Jetty bundle, which does not *see* any of the Equinox classes.

As far as the Equinox HTTP Service is concerned, the fragment approach is the right one for hooking into Jetty. If I'm reading the code path right, you could try the following things.

**(1) Set class loader on `ContextHandler`**

In your `JettyCustomizer.customizeContext` you should inspect the context. It should be a `ServletContextHandler`. Use its `setClassLoader` method to give it a class loader that knows about the Equinox classes (which any fragment of `org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty` should know anyway) and any other classes of your own custom code.

**(2) Fork/patch `JDBCSessionManager`**

If approach 1 does not work then you likely need to create your own fork of `JDBCSessionManager`. Extending might not work because of visibility issues (some methods are private). You need to override/patch/reimplement the `JDBCSessionManager.loadSession` method to use the correct class loader for loading. In the original implementation you can see why approach 1 should work (in theory). The code of your implementation can be much simpler, though.

If your fragment also imports the packages of your code, then simple use your fragment class loader. Otherwise you can create a custom one that delegates to the correct bundles for resolution.

Comment: A first try of option (1) seems get me a step further. I used ((ServletContextHandler)context).setClassLoader(org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.HttpServiceServlet.class.getClassLoader()), but now I am getting a new ClassNotFoundException, for one of our own classes which we store in the session. The own class is Serializable, but defined in our bundle, thus I guess not visible again. Same error. 2017-01-06 14:32:34.164:WARN:JDBCSessionManager:qtp1335669291-42: Unable to load session...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.synesty.servlet.AuthHolder cannot be found by org.eclipse.jetty.util...

Comment: I got it working with an own custom classloader which delegates to 2 different other classloaders in order to load classes from Equinox as well as from our own code. But now I am running into another Bug in Equinox for which I created https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510052 Once I finally get to a working solution I will post it here.

Comment: Good to see that the class loader approach works. Yes, the class loader need to "see" all bundles that put stuff into the session.

Comment: I got a similar issue that was caused by multiple Jetty versions being present on the class path. One coming from org.eclipse.help feature.xml the other from the embedded Spring jetty. If it can't decide which class to take it also responds with ClassNotFoundException. The issue could be solved by explicitly specifing the version to use in our own feature.xml.